# Angular 5 Service is returning data from api , but Component is not showing me the data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Most of this stuff in Angular 5 with typescript and rxjs with observables is pretty similar to angular 2, 4  - yet I seem to be having trouble with understanding WHY my component code is not showing data.

Here is my code

model:

```
export class arsCodes {
  iD: number;   
  aRSCode: string;
  aRSDescription: string;
  class: string;
  victimFlag: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  createdByUserID: string;
  createdOnDateTime: string;
  modifiedByUserID: string;
  modifiedOnDateTime: string;
}
```

Working Service

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

getArsCodesApi(search: arsCodes) {
  return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(search), httpOptions)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      response;
      console.log(response) // WORKS
    })
}
```

The "response" in console.log above returns { Status: "success", Message: "", data: Array(16) }

Then

```
 data: Array(16) 
 >0: {ID: 4443, ..... }  
 //etc..
```

However, it is in my call from the Component file in the subscribe that it is **undefined**

```
arsCode: ArsCode[];

this.arsSevice.getArsCodesApi(this.model).subscribe(
  result => {
    //this.arsCode = result
    console.log(result);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
)
```

**What do I need to do in my component to retrieve the data?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning anything in the .map() function of your service (which by using HttpClient is not required)

But anyways, you have to return like this:

```
return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(search), httpOptions)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't like console.log line  now   console.log(response)

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the map function. Include this code in your http petition to return data:

```
return this.http.post(this.serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(search), httpOptions)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Extraction from plain data are a simple return:

```
private extractData(res: Response): Observable<any> {
    return res|| { };
  }
```

Use return **res.json** for JSON data. You also can use this for error control:

```
 private handleError(error: any){
    return Observable.throw("Data unavailable or incorrect url");
  }
```